# Protractor wait() for debounced event + loading

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm trying to make my protractor tests to `wait` a condition, but I get inconsistent behaviour. The scenario is this one:

1. The user writtes some terms in a search box
2. A **debounced** event is fired. So, this depends on when the user stops typing.
3. We make an API request, meanwhile we show an `is loading` feedback and hide the `close button`.
4. Feedback dissapears, `close button` reapears, continue.

So, to achieve this I'm observing the `close button`. Between user stops writing and debounce event fires `close button` is visible. After debounced event fires (we're making request), `is loading` element shows and `close button` hides [1]. When is finished `close button` shows again.

Any idea is really appreciated, thanks!

1: To ease testing I've make `close button` dissapear at least 200ms, so that in localhost doesn't dissapear ultra-fast. This should be ok since webdriver polls every 100ms for the wait condition.

---

So, this is my test:

```
it('should show "no results" feedback when there are no results', function () {
    app.getHomepage();
    app.topMenu.searchLink.click();
    app.search.termsInput.sendKeys('chipijanders');
    app.search.waitForSearch();

    expect(app.search.noResults.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);

    // Checking the waitForSearch consistency
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        app.search.closeLink.click();
        app.topMenu.searchLink.click();
        app.search.termsInput.sendKeys('chipijanders');
        app.search.waitForSearch();
        expect(app.search.noResults.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
    }
});
```

---

And here `waitForSearch`:

```
waitForSearch: function () {
    var self = this;

    browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return self.closeLink.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
            return !isDisplayed;
        });
    });

    browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return self.closeLink.isDisplayed().then(function (isDisplayed) {
            return isDisplayed;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had an issue recently waiting for a decounced method in underscore. The solution I used was to override _.debounced in protractor.conf like so

```
onPrepare: function () {

    var debounceRightNow = function () {
        angular.module('debounceRightNow', []).run(
            function () {
                _.debounce = function (callback) {
                    return callback;
                };
            });
    };

    browser.addMockModule('debounceRightNow', debounceRightNow);
}
```

Not sure if that answers your question but it is a nifty solution

Comment: It's been a while since this issue happened, but it seems like a good approach to me.